# How to show random texts from a .txt file on my webpage each time the visitor reloads?

Tags: php

As example I have a list of texts on my .txt file.

```
text1
text2
text3
```

And I want to show only one text of them randomly selected from the .txt file using php.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @RiggsFolly No.But it should be simple for people who knows php well.

Comment: And it should not be super difficult for you to work on it, get started and ask a specific question.  See [ask] and [mvce].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.
in `$myFile` var insert your location file.
I remove 1 line from `$count` because array start from 0.

```
<?php
     //Path of file
     $myFile = "test_file.txt";
     //Read file from array
     $lines = file($myFile);
     //Get number line of file
     $lineTotal = count($lines);
     //Remove 1 line (start from 0)
     $count = $lineTotal-1;
     //Get casual number
     $number_casual = rand(0,$count);
     //Print line 2 ([0] = 1 ; [1] = 2 ; ...)
     echo $lines[$number_casual];
?>
```

Comment: It is not working. It is only showing the 2nd text on the file.

Comment: @user8481790 not understand.. you have a file .txt with example 10 row... You want see 1 casual row? Or what?

Comment: my txt file has 4 lines of texts but only the 2nd line is showing

Comment: Sorry my error... i edit my answer.. try now!!! (replace $lines[1] with $lines[$number_casual])

Comment: @user8481790 Sorry my error... i edit my answer.. try now!!! (replace $lines[1] with $lines[$number_casual]) . Now work?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Woirking now!